# fiscal period end date

Tags: estimation

If a quarterly report is released tomorrow, is there any way to figure out the date the quarterly period ended without manually researching? Such as an API?

I think there is a deadline of 35/60 days after period end, but that varies right? +-10 days of revenue can be a lot of error for an estimate, and I am seeing quarterly report periods vary in length.

Comment: You could only estimate it based on the publication date as there is just a deadline but no fixed date. But the report period of a quarterly report is always the same. A quarter. And this could give you another option: gather the previous quarterly (or annually) report and grep out the period end. Would this be possible or do you definitely just have access to the information that a report will be published tomorrow?

Comment: Its dangerous, I think, to estimate, because I see inconsistency between the date of publication and period end date. 
And, many companies seem to have inconsistent quarterly periods. Q3 this year can be 90 days, next year 110 days. 

I can find publication dates online, but not the dates covered in the quarterly report. 

Thanks for reply,